# Getting COLLATE LOCALIZED/UNICODE on non-Android SQLite

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I wanted to use `SQLiteAssetHelper` to create the SQLite database on my computer to use in an Android application. Unfortunately, I need an index using `COLLATE LOCALIZED`, which isn't built-in to standard SQLite. What is the simplest way to get `sqlite3.dll` with `COLLATE LOCALIZED` support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download ICU extension for SQLite (it's just a single C file to be compiled), then load it into SQLite with:

```
SELECT load_extension('C:\path\to\icu_extension.dll');
```

Then you can use a newly created SQL function to create collations:

```
SELECT icu_load_collation('en_US', 'LOCALIZED');
```